# Problem with my footer element: won't stay at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I wish to place my footer at the bottom of the page, but I've tried many things and none of them have worked.

The problem is: the footer is at the bottom of the page's standard height (no scroll), but when the page extends past that; that's where the problem occurs.
Code:

```
<div id="div">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/56AD30/fff.png&text=1" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/1560f0/fff.png&text=2" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/C03229/fff.png&text=3" />
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>Forever<span>Fit</span></h3>
            <div class="footer-links">
                <a class="left-links" href="#">Frakt & Leverans</a>
                <a class="left-links" href="#">Returrätt</a>
                <a class="left-links" href="#">Ångerrätt</a>
                <a class="left-links" href="#">FAQ</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p><span>Malmö</span>Sverige</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <p>Ett nummer</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <a href="mailto:support@company.com">Email@någonting</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <span>Om oss</span>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <div class="footer-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Css:

```
.footer {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #292c2f;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            font: bold 16px sans-serif;
            height: 270px;
            padding: 40px 30px;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .footer-left, .footer-center, .footer-right {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .footer-left {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .footer h3 {
            color: #ffffff;
            font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .footer h3 span {
            color: #5383d3;
        }

        .footer-links {
            color: #ffffff;
            margin: 20px 0 12px;
            padding: 0;
        }

                .footer-links a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    line-height: 1.8;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }

             .footer-company-name {
                color: #8f9296;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0;
            }

             .footer-center {
                width: 35%;
            }

                 .footer-center i {
                    background-color: #33383b;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    width: 38px;
                    height: 38px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 42px;
                    margin: 10px 15px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }

                     i.fa-envelope {
                        font-size: 17px;
                        line-height: 38px;
                    }

                 .footer-center p {
                    display: inline-block;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    margin: 0;
                }

                     .footer-center p span {
                        display: block;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        line-height: 25px;
                    }

                     .footer-center a {
                        color: #5383d3;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
             .footer-right {
                width: 20%;
                position: absolute;
                top: 24%;
            }

             .footer-company-about {
                line-height: 20px;
                color: #92999f;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0;
            }

                 .footer-company-about span {
                    display: block;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                }

             .footer-icons {
                margin-top: 25px;
            }

                 .footer-icons a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 35px;
                    height: 35px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    background-color: #33383b;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 35px;
                    margin-right: 3px;
                }
        .left-links {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        #div {
            position: absolute;
        }

        img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 2000px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 3;
            animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
        }

            img:nth-child(2) {
                z-index: 2;
                animation-delay: 4s;
            }

            img:nth-child(3) {
                z-index: 1;
                animation-delay: 8s;
            }

        @keyframes slideshow {
            25% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            33.33% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            91.66% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
```

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/n9kty7fh/ (excuse the slideshow; it's just there to show the problem.)

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Your JSFiddle has the footer as `position: absolute`, which shows the problem you are describing. However, your code in the question has `position: fixed` already - which keeps the footer stuck as you seem to want. Copying the code from your question into JSFiddle seems to work as desired. Hard to see what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, I described my problem quite pootly. But no worries, I solved it. What I wanted was for the footer to be at the very bottom of the page, not following the scroll as fixed does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, Here is the code.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Rishab2019/pen/oNjeOpz

```css
.footer {
            
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: #292c2f;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: left;
            font: bold 16px sans-serif;
            height: 270px;
            padding: 40px 30px;
            margin-top: 50px;
        }

        .footer-left, .footer-center, .footer-right {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: bottom;
        }

        .footer-left {
            width: 40%;
        }

        .footer h3 {
            color: #ffffff;
            font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .footer h3 span {
            color: #5383d3;
        }

        .footer-links {
            color: #ffffff;
            margin: 20px 0 12px;
            padding: 0;
        }

                .footer-links a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    line-height: 1.8;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #ffffff;
                }

             .footer-company-name {
                color: #8f9296;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0;
            }

             .footer-center {
                width: 35%;
            }

                 .footer-center i {
                    background-color: #33383b;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    width: 38px;
                    height: 38px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 42px;
                    margin: 10px 15px;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                }

                     i.fa-envelope {
                        font-size: 17px;
                        line-height: 38px;
                    }

                 .footer-center p {
                    display: inline-block;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    vertical-align: middle;
                    margin: 0;
                }

                     .footer-center p span {
                        display: block;
                        font-weight: normal;
                        font-size: 14px;
                        line-height: 25px;
                    }

         .footer-center a {
                        color: #5383d3;
                        text-decoration: none;
                    }
             .footer-right {
                width: 20%;
                position: absolute;
                
            }

             .footer-company-about {
                line-height: 20px;
                color: #92999f;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: normal;
                margin: 0;
            }

                 .footer-company-about span {
                    display: block;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    font-size: 14px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                }

   .footer-icons {
           margin-top: 25px;
            }

                 .footer-icons a {
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 35px;
                    height: 35px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    background-color: #33383b;
                    border-radius: 4px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height: 35px;
                    margin-right: 3px;
                }
        .left-links {
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
       

        img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 2000px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 3;
            animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
        }

            img:nth-child(2) {
                z-index: 2;
                animation-delay: 4s;
            }

            img:nth-child(3) {
                z-index: 1;
                animation-delay: 8s;
            }

        @keyframes slideshow {
            25% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            33.33% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            91.66% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }


#page-container {
  position: relative;
  
}

@media all and (max-width:859px){
  .footer{
    height:310px;
    
  }
  
  
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
<div id="div">
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/56AD30/fff.png&text=1" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/1560f0/fff.png&text=2" />
        <img src="http://dummyimage.com/280x200/C03229/fff.png&text=3" />
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>Forever<span>Fit</span></h3>
            <div class="footer-links">
                <a class="left-links" href="#">Frakt & Leverans</a>
                <a class="left-links" href="#">Returrätt</a>
                <a class="left-links" href="#">Ångerrätt</a>
                <a class="left-links" href="#">FAQ</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-center">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p><span>Malmö</span>Sverige</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                <p>Ett nummer</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <a href="mailto:support@company.com">Email@någonting</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <span>Om oss</span>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <div class="footer-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you just add a container div to all of my code and put it to relative?! That fixed it?? And by the way, should this page-container contain everything in the website? As I didn't include exactly all of my code, only the necessary parts. Thanks for the help as well!

Comment: Adding container doesn't really solve the problem.There are many other things which fixed, like removing position element from footer, mobile view fix, and it's done.yay!

Comment: It's not necessary to add all the code in container.

Comment: But you should add all elements in the container to contain all the things and that will be good for the page.If you like my answer, please accept it as answer.Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Before the edit, my answer was pretty useless for @Exiits, so I deleted that part.

Now, as for your answer, Your code is perfect, only with the exception of `position: absolute;`. Remove `position` from `.footer` and `.footer-company-about` and make the width 100vw so that the footer meets the left and right edges of the page.

Why does the footer not remain at the bottom with the slideshow?

It is because, the slideshow has `position:absolute;` which enables it to have height more than the body itself. The footer is positioned at the bottom of the body, which is above the slideshow, and that is why you were facing the problem.

This also means, that your footer cannot (most probably) reach the bottom of the slideshow.

Edit:
here's a code which should be just what you wanted-

```css
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #292c2f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: left;
  font: bold 16px sans-serif;
  height: 270px;
  padding: 40px 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.footer-left,
.footer-center,
.footer-right {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.footer-left {
  width: 40%;
}

.footer h3 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font: normal 36px 'Cookie', cursive;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer h3 span {
  color: #5383d3;
}

.footer-links {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 20px 0 12px;
  padding: 0;
}

.footer-links a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.8;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.footer-company-name {
  color: #8f9296;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-center {
  width: 35%;
}

.footer-center i {
  background-color: #33383b;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
  margin: 10px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

i.fa-envelope {
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.footer-center p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-center p span {
  display: block;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.footer-center a {
  color: #5383d3;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-right {
  width: 20%;
  top: 24%;
}

.footer-company-about {
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #92999f;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

.footer-company-about span {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.footer-icons {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.footer-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #33383b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.left-links {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 2000px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*
                img:nth-child(2) {
                    z-index: 2;
                    animation-delay: 4s;
                }

                img:nth-child(3) {
                    z-index: 1;
                    animation-delay: 8s;
                }*/

@keyframes slideshow {
  25% {
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/280x200/56AD30/fff.png&text=1");
  }

  33.33% {
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/280x200/1560f0/fff.png&text=2");
  }

  91.66% {
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/280x200/C03229/fff.png&text=3");
  }

  100% {
    background-image: url("http://dummyimage.com/280x200/56AD30/fff.png&text=1");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTPYE html>
  <html>

    <body>

      <div class="img"></div>
        <footer class="footer">
          <div class="footer-left">
            <h3>Forever<span>Fit</span></h3>
            <div class="footer-links">
              <a class="left-links" href="#">Frakt & Leverans</a>
              <a class="left-links" href="#">Returrätt</a>
              <a class="left-links" href="#">Ångerrätt</a>
              <a class="left-links" href="#">FAQ</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-center">
            <div>
              <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
              <p><span>Malmö</span>Sverige</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
              <p>Ett nummer</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
              <a href="mailto:support@company.com">Email@någonting</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
              <span>Om oss</span>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
            </p>
            <div class="footer-icons">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
    </body>

  </html>
```

The changes I made to your code are-

1. The changes I mentioned above
2. Replaced the img tags with a single div tag.
3. In the animation, the background url changes now.
4. Minor changes, like adding `overflow: auto;` in the footer etc. (Mostly irrelevant)

Comment: Oh yes sorry. Forgot to update. But it still doesn't work. Fixed doesn't work. I've tried it. What fixed does is it follows as the page is getting scrolled, which is not what I want. I want the footer to stay at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Okay, I've tried what you have suggested, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. You see, I need the slideshow to be "position: absolute" for it to work, otherwise all pictures will be displayed. Now with the footer. What happened with my footer when I edited was that instead of going down to the bottom of the page; it seems to have went all the way to the top for some odd reason.

Comment: Ok. Editing again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you two for helping! With the help of the both codes and a bit of my own I've finally solved it! Again, thanks for the help! What I did was adding a `<div>` to contain the whole footer, and in css:

```
.footer-container {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0;
   top: 500%; 
}
```